# Add Background to Facebook Like Button on Sidebar

Tags: html, facebook, background, facebook-like

I am trying to add facebook like button and twitter follow button to SIT on a background although I have tried many variations of coding nothing works.

Lets say I have this image/background http://cl.ly/3A050D3E0v0X1C332O0c

and I want facebook/twitter to be under that background to look nice and then implement that code as an HTML widget on my wordpress sidebar.

Is this possible?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you want to apply a background to the area in which the Facebook like button will reside?

Answer (score 0):

Place the like button inside of a **div** and set the background image of the **div** using CSS.

Comment: I am not trying to change the style of the button but more like add it above a static image to look nice.